# Tool tip not showing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have implemented a tool tip to show the data. The script seems to be working fine but data is not getting displayed.It does display the alert message when I hover over but i want to display the custom data
Any pointers please

Javascript for tooltip :

```
$('.tt_sub').hover(function () {
   alert("HELLO");
   $('.tt_sub').tooltip({title: function () {
     return $(this).attr('name');
   }
  });
});
```

php CODE

```
<tbody>
        <?php

        $weekday = ["", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

        for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
            ?><tr><td><?php echo $weekday[$i] ?></td>
                <?php
                for ($j = 1; $j <= sizeof($slot_id); $j++) {
                    ?>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-row"  >
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input class="cb_tt" id="<?php echo $slot_id[$j] ?>" name="<?php echo $i ?>" type="checkbox"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3 tt_sub" id="<?php echo $slot_id[$j].$i ?>">

                            </div>
                            <div style="display: none;" class="tt_tea" id="<?php echo $slot_id[$j].$i ?>">

                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <?php
                }
                ?></tr><?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: `.tt_sub` doesnt have a `name` attribute

Comment: @Alex didnt get it

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tt_sub').tooltip({
  title: function () {
    return $(this).closest('.form-row').find('.cb_tt').attr('name');
  }
});
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer